# Why does Git use a colon (:<branch>) to delete remote branches?

Tags: git

Why does Git use

```
git push <remote> :<branch>
```

as in

```
git push origin :featureA
```

to delete the branch `featureA` from the remote server?

I am interested in why the colon was used as the delete flag.

It's so different from `git branch -d <localbranch>`.

Why don't we do something like

```
git branch -d --remote origin <branchname>
```

or is there a deeper meaning behind the colon symbol that I didn't know?

Comment: For deleting remote branches, there's now a prettier syntax [`git push origin --delete foobar`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html#Deleting-Remote-Branches)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It is not the meaning of the `:` per se, but what is present, or rather absent before it.

The refspec format is

```
<+><source>:<destination>
```

(optional + for non-fast forward)

So when you do something like `git push origin :featureA`, you are specifying an empty source ref and basically making the destination "empty" or deleting it.

PS: Note that the refspec of `:` or nothing doesn't mean push nothing to nothing however. It makes git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side.

Comment: Git >=1.7.0 added `git push origin -d <branch>` to delete and `git push origin -D <branch>` to force delete a remote branch.

Comment: So when would you put something before the :?

Comment: @ITIA when your local branch has a different name than the remote one.

Answer (score 34):

The colon isn't a "delete flag". Note that [git push](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) and [git pull](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) both accept zero or more refspecs as their final argument(s). Now [read about refspecs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec). A colon separates source from destination in a refspec. The command `git push origin :foo` has an empty source and essentially says "push *nothing* to branch foo of origin", or, in other words, "make branch foo on origin not exist".

Comment: IMO, your answer doesn't answer the question for the following reason: if I try to push a branch whose history has diverged, I need to force push the branch. However, this is not the case when deleting a branch using `:foo`. An empty branch does not share history with an existing remote branch and so it cannot, the way I see it, overwrite an existing remote branch with an empty branch. Something feels wrong with your answer.

Comment: @Umang: afaik, it's only a conceptual thing, and I didn't say "push an empty branch". I said "push nothing". I don't disagree with your assessment that it would make more sense with a "+" in front of it, but this is just how it works. See the [last section](http://progit.org/book/ch9-5.html#deleting_references) of the refspecs link I posted, and decide whether you trust the author.