# How to delete git branch that have same name as tag?

Tags: git

In my project I've deleted all old branches that was hanging in git, but some branches I was not be able to remove:

```
$ git push origin :0.2.0.0
error: dst refspec 0.2.0.0 matches more than one.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@<repo>.git'
```

I have few git repos and I have some old branches that was probably created by mistake. Those branches have the same name as a tag that was created and I'm not able to delete those branches.

Is there a way to delete those branches? It seems that the only command that you can find anywhere is `git push origin :<branch>` or `git push -d origin <branch>` and there are not distinction between branch and tag in those commands.

I have no idea how those branches were created, but I would like to get rid of them.

Comment: `:0.2.0.0` is a branch name?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've written this in the question, I have branch and tag with same name.

Comment: What is the name of the branch? Having a branch and tag with the same name should be no issue? --- Also, this may help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7303710/989920

Comment: Alrighty, what about removing the tag locally? And then using `git push <remote> :refs/tags/<tagname>`? From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-tag

Comment: That works, the details are in the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> dst refspec 0.2.0.0 matches more than one

Normally this isn't a problem but here [git doesn't know which `0.2.0.0` this refers to](https://github.com/git/git/blob/142430338477d9d1bb25be66267225fb58498d92/remote.c#L1178-L1200), the solution is to be [more explicit](https://www.programmersought.com/article/15361044616/).

## To delete the branch

To take care of the scenario in the question:

```
$ git push origin :refs/heads/0.2.0.0
```

## To delete the tag

And for completeness, if it was the tag that was unwanted:

```
$ git push origin :refs/tags/0.2.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact meaning of the "refspec" argument to "git push" is quite complicated, and [discussed at length in the git manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

The most relevant part is this:

> If  doesn’t start with refs/ (e.g. refs/heads/master) we will try to infer where in refs/* on the destination `<repository>` it belongs based on the type of `<src>` being pushed and whether `<dst>` is ambiguous.

In other words, naming just the branch or tag is actually short-hand for naming a specific pointer in the "refs/" directory of the git repository.

To be more explicit, you can point to a specific entry in that directory:

- Branches are stored in "refs/heads/", so "refs/heads/ABC" refers unambiguously to a branch
- Tags are stored in "refs/tags/", so "refs/tags/ABC" refers unambiguously to a tag
- Other refs can be used for other purposes; for instance, Github uses "refs/pull/123/head" and "refs/pull/123/merge" to refer to the current tip, and current merge result, of open Pull Request "123"